# Using the MS RawPrinterHelper Class for PDF Files

Tags: c#, vb.net

I been have problems using MS RawPrinterHelper Class printing a pdf file.I can get txt files to print fine. I passing the name of the printer and pdf bytes to the printer RawPrinterHelper but nothing will print. Any help is great

Comment: why won't you use any other pdf export plugin ?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand how can pdf export plugin help me with printing?

Comment: I though that you are trying to use the MS RawPrinterHelper to print your content into a PDF file..and save the file.. if so there are components that can do that without using the printer and relay on the user to have the necessary "PDF printer Drivers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private static void printLables(byte[] LabelFile)
    {

    string s = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(LabelFile);
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Your Printer Name";

    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, s);
    }
```

Let me know if this work for you.